# Matrix operations on only part of vertex buffer (opengl-tutorial.org)

Tags: c++, opengl

I recently learned that:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

is not really how its done.  I've been working with the tutorials at [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/) which introduced me to VBOs.  Now I'm migrating it all into a class and trying to refine my understanding. 
My situation is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951509/modern-opengl-vbo-glm-and-matrix-stacks).  I understand how to use matrices for rotations and I could do it all myself then hand it over to gl and friends.  But I'm sure thats far less efficient and it would involve more communication with the graphics card.  Tutorial 17 on that website shows how to rotate things, it uses:

```
// Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
// in the "MVP" uniform
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ViewMatrix[0][0]);
```

to rotate objects.  I assume this is more efficient then anything I could ever produce.  What I want is to do something like this, but only multiply the matrix by some of the mesh, without breaking the mesh into pieces (because that would disrupt the triangle-vertex-index relationship and I'd end up stitching it back together manually).

Is there a separate function for that? Is there some higher level library that handles meshes and bones that I should be using (as some of the replies to the other guys post seems to suggest)? I don't want to get stuck using something outdated and inefficient again, only to end up redoing everything again later.

Comment: Turns out the correct answer was what Nicol Bolas recommended with the stipulation that the shader is something you can modify in a special scripting language GLSL and not some kind of library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniforms are so named because they are *uniform*: unchanging over the course of a render call. Shaders can only operate on input values (which are provided per input type. Per-vertex for vertex shaders, per-fragment for fragment shaders, etc), uniforms (which are fixed for a single rendering call), and global variables (which are reset to their original values for every instantiation of a shader).

If you want to do different stuff for different parts of an object within a single rendering call, you must do this based on *input variables*, because only inputs change within a single rendering call. It sounds like you're trying to do something with matrix skinning or hierarchies of objects, so you probably want to give each vertex a matrix index or something as an input. You use this index to look up a uniform matrix *array* to get the actual matrix you want to use.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly you're saying each vertex not only can have its coordinates, its normal, its texture coordinates, but also a matrix membership index.

Comment: That sounds like it would accomplish what I want. Do you have (preferably) a code example for me to look at?  Or a list of relevant gl functions?  Or is this something I write myself (without taking advantage of graphics card?)?

Comment: @gunfulker: A vertex consists of whatever data you want it to have. Nothing is a "position" or a "normal" unless you *decide* that it is.

Comment: I know, I tell opengl its a vertex (in this example) with `GLuint vertexPosition_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition_modelspace");` and a normal with `GLuint vertexNormal_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexNormal_modelspace");` and texture `"vertexUV"`. Functions from `GLEW`. How do I tell opengl to treat it as a matrix index or array of matrices? I need an example website or at least some function names to google, I haven't been able to find anything like this.

Comment: @gunfulker: That's not telling OpenGL to treat something as a position or normal. You do that *implicitly*, in your shader. Those are just *words*; they don't mean anything to OpenGL. A position is a position because you *treat* it like a position in your shader code. You multiply it by matrices and stick the result in `gl_Position`. A normal is a normal because you use it to do lighting computations. It's *arbitrary code*; values have the meaning that your code gives them. A "matrix index" is a value you use to index an array of matrices.

Comment: Its a `GLEW` function that gets the associated `GLuint` for `glVertexAttribPointer`'s 1st argument which is what tells opengl what to do with it.  But lets forget that.  I just want *anything* that can tell me how to find examples of what you are describing with the matrix arrays and matrix indices. Before now I had never heard of this, and even now I can't find anything with the information provided so far. What is it called? It seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is not a scene graph. It doesn't think in meshes or geometry. When you specify a uniform, it won't get "applied" to the mesh. It merely sets a register to be accessed by a shader. Later when you draw primitives from a Vertex Array (maybe contained in a VBO), the call to `glDraw…` determines which parts of the VA are batched for drawing. It's perfectly possible and reasonable to `glDraw…` just a subset of the VA, then switch uniforms, and draw another subset.

In any case OpenGL will not change the data in the VA.

Comment: It doesn't change the originals, yes.  I now see how I could easily do it by adapting the 2nd argument in `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,(void*)0);` .  Nicol Bolas's answer sounds even better suited and I'd appreciate more information on that.

Comment: @gunfulker: This works by adding an integer attribute to the vertex, that designates which codepath the shaders should follow. In the shader code do a conditional (= if statement) on said vertex attribute to select which "sub"shader to execute.