# Return to the original openGL origin coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm currently trying to solve a problem regarding the display of an arm avatar.
I'm using a 3D tracker that's sending me coordinates and angles through my serial port. It works quite fine as long as I only want to show a "hand" or a block of wood in its place in 3D space.
The problem is: When I want to draw an entire arm (lets say the wrist is "stiff"), so the only degree of freedom is the elbow), I'm using the given coordinates (to which I've gltranslatef'd and glmultmatrix'd), but I want to draw another quad primitive with 2 vertices that are relative to the tracker coordinates (part of the "elbow") and 2 vertices that are always fixed next to the camera (part of the "shoulder"). However, I can't get out of my translated coordinate system.
Is my question clear?
My code is something like

```
cubeStretch = 0.15;

computeRotationMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(handX, handY, handZ);
glMultMatrixf(*rotationMatrix);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
/*some vertices for the "block of wood"*/
/*then a vertex which is relative to handX-handZ*/
glVertex3f(-cubeStretch, -cubeStretch+0.1, 5+cubeStretch);
/*and here I want to go back to the origin*/
gltranslatef(-handX, -handY, -handZ);
/*so the next vertex should preferably be next to the camera; the shoulder, so to say*/
glVertex3f(+0.5,-0.5,+0.5);
```

I already know the last three line don't work, it's just one of the ways I've tried.
I realize it might be hard to understand what I'm trying to do. Anyone got any idea on how to get back to the "un-gltranslatef'd" coordinate origin?

(I'd rather avoid having to implement a whole bone/joint system for this.)

Edit:https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/699x439q90/202/uefw.png

In the picture you can see what I have so far. As you can see, the emphasis so far has not been on beauty, but rather on using the tracker coordinates to correctly display something on the screen.

The white cubes are target points which turn red when the arm avatar "touches" them ("arm avatar" used here as a word for the hideous brown contraption to the right, but I think you know what I mean). I now want to have a connection from the back end of the "lower arm" (the broad end of the avatar is supposed to be the hand) to just the right of the screen. Maybe it's clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

a) The fixed function stack is deprecated and you shouldn't use it. Use a proper matrix math library (like GLM), make copies of the branching nodes in your transformation hierarchy so that you can use those as starting point for different branches.

b) You can reset the matrix state to identity at any time using glLoadIdentity. Using glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix you can create a stack. You know how stacks work, do you? Pushing makes a copy and adds it to the top, all following operations happen on that. Poping removes the element at the top and gives you back the state it was in before the previous push.

---

#### Update

Regarding transformation trees you may be interested in the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953078/524368
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566740/524368

> (I'd rather avoid having to implement a whole bone/joint system for this.)

It's actually the most easy way to do this. In terms of fixed function OpenGL a bone-joint is just a combination of `glTranslate(…); glRotate(…)`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean with point a). (Might be since my English has become quite rusty) Is it that my methods are "unmodern"? I learned openGL over the past year using tutorials from around the web and trial-and-error. Is "dynamic pipeline" a keyword I should be looking into?
As to b), neither glLoadIdentity() nor glPopMatrix() helped while between glBegin(GL_QUADS) and glEnd().

Comment: @ElRentier: I should hope not, those commands are not valid between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. Move them outside of those blocks.

Comment: That's what I thought. Unfortunately, I want to go from the tracker coordinates back to the origin and back to the tracker _while_ drawing a single QUAD. :(

Comment: @ElRentier: You can not modify the transformation matrices between glBegin and glEnd. If you want to transform single vertices you'll have to do this manually and pass the pre-transformed vertices to OpenGL. If you just want to transform whole quads, you have to do that in multiple glBegin…glEnd blocks. Or better yet: Do not use glBegin…glEnd at all, but do the proper thing and use Vertex Arrays, preferrably with the data contained in VBOs.

Comment: @ElRentier: Regarding point a): Yes your way of doing things is unmodern. It's been out of fashion for well over 10 years. Immediate mode is slow and cumbersome to use. You want to use vertex arrays. And instead of fixed function transformations you should use the modern programmable pipeline. I recommend http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut for a tutorial on modern OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will definitely look into those tutorials. However, let's pretend I have to get this to work reaaaaally soon and don't really know my stuff (for example, I didn't think of the origin coord problem until today).

So when you say "transform vertices manually" how would I generally go about this? And since there are a lot of vertices to be drawn around the tracker coordinates and (at least) one next to the origin, it would be the smartest idea to pre-transform that one vertex, right? Would I have to put calculations (sin,cos,...) into the glVertex3f() call?

Comment: @ElRentier: This is really difficult to tell without knowing exactly what you want to achieve. If it is some robot arm you want to move around, just split it into several rigid meshes and transform each mesh individually. (Don't think in quads, think in meshes). If however you want to deform a mesh, then you'd have to look into skeletal animation and vertex shaders (the term would be "matrix palette skinning"). Ideally you'd post some picture (a hand drawn sketch) of what you want to do into your question, so that we know what you want to do.

Comment: @datenwolf: I edited the original post. Turns out I can not post pictures because of my low reputation. Hope the linked picture helps to clear things up!